# Create remote P2 eclipse update site?

Tags: eclipse

I have created an eclipse update site using the Plugin project wizard in eclipse helios. I have added some features to this site and build it and it works fine (I can add the site to the update manager in eclipse).

Now I would like to move this update site to a server so it can be accessed globally. But where do I find info on setting up a server and how to move the site to the correct folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple: you need a server that can serve files over HTTP. You upload your update site to the server. You will have plugins and features directories and all the relevant XMLs or compressed XMLs (depends on how you created it).

For example, if your server is at http://update.example.com/ and your doc-root is at /var/docroot then all these files go under /var/docroot, so you will have /var/docroot/plugins, /var/docroot/features, etc.

Again, very simple, simply copy the local update site to the server and unjar it if it is an archive.

Answer (score 1):

Try p2-maven-plugin: http://projects.reficio.org/p2-maven-plugin/manual.html

It can do both generate and expose the P2 update site using the HTTP protocol.